# Searching for [java] very slow at the moment?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

If I search for a particular tag (e.g. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), it takes over 10 seconds for Stack Overflow to come back.  All the assets for the site are loaded very quickly (I checked with a cleared cache), and [speedtest.net](http://speedtest.net) reports that my connection is fine, so I'm wondering if it's an issue with the new data centres?

Comment: I don't see this in `[python]`, but for `[java]` or `[php]` it is indeed dog-slow.

Comment: Updated question title to better reflect the tag-specific nature of slowdown

Comment: `[c#]` seems to be having the same.

Comment: JavaScript and PHP as well. So much for the JVM joke I had ready.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: I feel strangely validated in my choice of favourite programming language.

Comment: I've experimented a little more. I *thought* it was just the top tags sorted by popularity that are affected, but [`[android]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) works just fine, while [`[java]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [`[c#]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [`[javascript]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [`[php]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [`[jquery]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), and [`[html]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) are all affected.

Comment: Beyond these everything else in the top 40 load snappily.

Comment: [Review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review) is also really slow.

Comment: As a sidenote: I have a search query with over 20 tags including `[c#]` and `[java]` and new/modified questions appear there straight away which might indicate it is limited to single-query searches. You'll notice that this one works instantly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+jquery

Comment: So we'll tag all the questions with [jquery] @JeroenVannevel. Problem fixed.

Comment: I don't notice anything searching for `[java]`, but going to [the review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review) is ***so*** slow...

Comment: Hah! If you think _that's slow_ - try searching for `****` , that matches _every question ever_.

Comment: Tag filtering for review (including those little indicators on the tag pages) is being *really slow* at the moment - we obviously need a better caching system here, but until then we're turning off the quick links to tag filters so that performance is reasonable here.

Comment: Review queues are really slow today as well

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in comments, this was originally fixed by simply disabling the feature that caused it. Jarrod has since added some caching and the performance problems should be resolved - please let us know if this resurfaces.