# Community♦ should not poke "unanswered" questions with status-tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, community-user

It looks like [Community♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/-1) pokes unanswered questions (no upvoted or accepted answers) indiscriminately.

While getting them some more attention might be worthwhile often, that's certainly not the case if some moderator gave an official verdict with one of the [status-*]-tags.

Case from today:
[Searching for [java] very slow at the moment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260551)

Can we stop community♦ from poking those?

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11576/on-meta-have-community-ignore-status-tags-when-bumping

Comment: Thanks for the MSE-post. Anyway, gave Shog an upvote to stop *that* question from being bumped again. Any re-thinking since? (That post is from 2009...)

Comment: Just because SE has labeled something status-declined doesn't mean the community agree. Equally; there are some "completed" feature-requests on meta that still have questions asked about them.

Comment: I still find Jeff's argument rather convincing. What has changed with regard to this issue since 2009? What is your counter-argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Jeff's reasoning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60022/50049) for keeping the behavior as-is still stands; we should be providing an answer when we 'close out' a bug or feature request with a status tag.

The fact that we're not doing that consistently shouldn't make canceling the bumps any more attractive. It should rather continue to point out that we need to be more conscious about adding our own answer.

Why?

- So the OP of the bug / feature isn't pinged with a barrage of stuff as people engage with us in comments - that should happen under an answer we own.
- So people can vote on our response, or share / link to it directly.
- It's just the right thing to do.

I can't promise when it'll be more uncommon to see something we didn't answer directly than common, but I'd hate to remove essentially the only thing reminding us that we need to get better at something. Complacency tends to undermine mindful competence, and we already sort of suck in this department.

Let's leave it as-is while we work to get a whole lot of other stuff done.

Comment: I've noticed documentation (or was it jobs?) bugs/feature requests regularly get a status tag without an answer being posted.

Comment: @Stijn I think we need a way internally to status- a bunch of stuff that's essentially fixed or implemented by the same thing in one fell swoop (that would really help especially during super noisy and busy beta building). A way that allows us to provide a single answer and ultimately merge? Have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: In theory us mortals could also write an answer for some of  those status-* questions. I personally always exclude them when I search for candidate questions to be answered. Can you share your preference for us answering questions tagged status-*?

Comment: It would have been much more fitting had you elected to not answer this question and simply mark it as declined.