# Job Dismissal: "Something Went Wrong. Our Best People Are On It"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

For the last couple of days I haven't been able to dismiss jobs. On clicking the dismiss link, I get an exclamation mark with the text:

> Oops! Something went wrong. Don't worry, our best people are on it!

[image: screenshot of the alert]

I am using FF 51.0a2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: reproduced on Chrome latest & windows 10.

Comment: Hey, I work on the ads team at Stack. Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I'll take a stab at it ASAP!

Comment: Hmm. So your best people were on a break?

Comment: They only promised the best people. They didn't promise the best people were also *fast*.

Comment: Should be fixed. Thanks for pinging us about it

Comment: @HoriaComan Can you post that as an answer? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341498 :)

Comment: @Stijn added an answer as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug affected all platforms and all people. It was easy to reproduce.

It was introduced about two days ago, while we were trying to fix another issue.

Hopefully the new fix clears issues in that particular behaviour for good.

Comment: Confirmed. The job was dismissed.