# How are questions handled on meta?

Tags: discussion, meta

When a question is asked on meta, usually users, moderators, or even SE employees would response to it by writing answers. However, sometimes there would be no answers, despite many comments left. Example: [Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340703/5399734)

I want to know how questions on meta are handled:

- Do all meta questions deserve an answer?
- What the procedure/policy of handling meta questions?
- Does Stack Exchange Inc. have employees dedicated to reading and answering questions on each meta site?
- Is there something like a regular meeting discussing popular meta questions in Stack Exchange Inc.?
- etc.

I want each meta question to receive at least one answer, preferably within a week, because unanswered questions give me an impression of being ignored or forgotten by the community.

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40434/why-are-there-so-many-feature-request-with-no-official-response) on Meta SE.

Comment: I was onboard until *"I want each meta question to receive at least one answer, preferably within a week"*.  You can't ask *"do all meta questions deserve an answer"* and then, without waiting for the the answer to that question, demand answers to each question in a timely manner. It's perfectly reasonable for questions to go unanswered on meta, where open-ended discussion in comments is (slightly) less discouraged. Not all questions have good answers.

Answer (score 9):

This varies per (required) tag:

- [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions are the ones which look the most like questions on the main site; one user has a problem, and another user (often a Meta regular) can post a solution or workaround as the answer.
- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions are often answered quickly as well, but in a style which looks more like a forum than a Q&A site. Again, this is usually done by a Meta regular or a ♦ moderator.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions can often only be 'answered' by *implementing* the requested feature or *solving* the bug, which needs to be done by a Stack Overflow employee, and that takes [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232).

> I want each meta question to receive at least one answer, preferably within a week, because unanswered questions give me an impression of being ignored or forgotten by the community.

For some question, there simply isn't an answer. Also, how does the string of comments below [the specific question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340703/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post) give an impression of being ignored?

Comment: I wanted an answer to my question, but all I got were these dumb comments.

Answer (score 7):

> Do all meta questions deserve an answer?

No, only questions that are worth it. It also requires that someone has both the time and the knowledge to answer.

> What the procedure/policy of handling meta questions?

The same as on main: someone post a question, it appears on the "active" tab, and users pay attention to it. Once it stops being bumped or hot, the community essentially forgets about it.

> Does Stack Exchange Inc. have employees dedicated to reading and answering questions on each meta site?

Stack Overflow—the company that is—has [Community Managers](https://stackoverflow.com/company/team#Community) on the payroll. One of their jobs is to follow questions on Meta sites. If they see fit, they might answer as well. ([They are trying to get better at doing this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271132/community-should-not-poke-unanswered-questions-with-status-tags/341498#341498).) One of the developers is often on [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) watch.

> Is there something like a regular meeting discussing popular meta questions in Stack Exchange Inc.?

The team surely uses a chatroom to discuss posts if warranted. I do hope they don't spend hours in meetings. If they have that much time, they better post an answer.

> etc.

etc.

> I want each meta question to receive at least one answer, preferably within a week

There is no [guaranteed pipeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange).